# C++ vector of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

Why does this work:

```
std::pair<int, int> p = {1,2};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vp = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

But this doesn't?

```
std::array<int, 2> a = {1,2}; // still ok
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> va = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

Using g++ 4.5.1 with `-std=c++0x`, the second line fails with:

> error: could not convert `‘{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}’` to `‘std::vector<std::array<int, 2u> >’`

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify "fails"? (like give your compiler's error?)

Comment: Which OS? Might be a compiler bug

Comment: @VJo @mat more details added, thanks!

Comment: I am actually suspecting that gcc 4.5.1 is not fully compliant on this matter. Unfortunately I don't know an online compiler that could help here (ideone uses 4.5.1).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, `std::array` does not have an initializer list constructor. Indeed, it has *no* user-defined constructor whatsoever -- this "feature" is a leftover from C++03 where omitting all user-defined constructors was the only way to enable the C-style brace initialization. It is IMHO a defect in the current standard.

So why doesn't built-in brace initialization work in this case? Let's see what `std::array` looks like under the hood:

```
template <typename T, int i> struct array {
    T data[i];
    // ...
}
```

Ok, so doesn't that mean we'd have to use *double* braces in the initializer (one pair for `array`, another pair for the `data` member?

```
std::array<int, 2> a = { {1, 2} };
```

C (and consequently C++) has a special rule about *brace elision*, permitting the omission of the inner braces unless there is an ambiguity. `array` exploits this feature, allowing us to write

```
std::array<int, 2> a = { 1, 2 };
```

So why doesn't the example in the original post work? Because brace elision is only permitted in the context of a C-style aggregate initialization, not if there's anything more complicated involved, such as an user-defined initializer list constructor.

The following *should* work, though, as ugly as it is:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> vp = { {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} };
```

The fact that it does not, at least on gcc 4.5 and gcc 4.6, seems to me to indicate a compiler bug. I'm not completely sure about it, though.

This question is somewhat relevant: [How do I initialize a member array with an initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549524/how-do-i-initialize-a-member-array-with-an-initializer-list)

Comment: I rather suspect that `std::array` looks more like `template <typename T, std::size_t i>`

Comment: Yes, your last example should work. It was a conscious and discussed decision not to support brace elision for anything other than a simple `T t = { ... }` declaration. That's also why `return { ... }` will not work with a `std::array<>` return type.

Comment: Your last example    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> vp = { {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} };    works on gcc 4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> va = {
  std::array<int, 2>{1,2},
  std::array<int, 2>{3,4}
};
```

Digging deeper, it seems that std::pair has a constructor that takes an initialiser list, but std::array doesn't:

```
std::pair<int, int> p ({1,2}) ;  // OK
std::array<int, 2> a ({1,2}) ;   // Invalid
```

But now I'm out of my depth.

Comment: you actually made here it for the compiler to infer the types of the elements in the curly brace initializer list. I guess that's where the problem lies, but still do not know whether it should work per the standard or not.