# std::array implicit initialization in function call

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can outer braces be omitted in an initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)

I'm using `std::array` in Visual Studio 2010, which is actually `std::tr1::array` and I'm running into an annoying issue. I have a function which takes an `array` as an argument, for instance.

`void do_something(std::tr1::array<int, 5> data)`

Calling the function like `do_something({1,2,3});` doesn't work and results in a compiler error, however

```
std::tr1::array<int, 5> data = {1,2,3};
do_something(data);
```

does. I don't really see why the former wouldn't work. The errors I get tell me I'm missing a `)` before the `{`. This leads me to believe it's not expecting an initialization list, but I don't see why not. Am I misusing initialization lists?

edit: `std::tr1::array` isn't necessary, `std::array` works fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
do_something({{1,2,3}});
```

`std::array` uses 2 sets of braces to initialize, but in certain cases (such as that example you posted) you can elide the outer spurious braces. This might help: [C++11: Correct std::array initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14178264/964135)

Comment: same here, same compiler..

Comment: It works on my GCC: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0db4e5670d751282ca5cd244708bd38a I suppose MSVC doesn't support brace initialization fully.

Comment: yeah, OP mentioned VS2010 I guess it's not supported so far

Comment: Yeah looks like VS2010 doesn't support it, I just assumed it would because it does outside a function call. Oh well!

Answer (score 3):

The extra braces is needed because `std::array` is an aggregate and POD, unlike other containers in the standard library. `std::array` doesn't have user-defined constructor. It's first data member is an array of size `N` (which you pass as template argument), and this member is directly initialized with initializer. The extra braces is needed for the *internal* array which is directly being initialized.

Think of this as:

```
struct A
{
     int data[2];
};
```

How many braces you need when you create an instance of `A` ?

```
A a{1,2};      //wrong as per the Standard (the compiler might allow it)
A b{ {1,2 } }; //correct
```

In `b`, the outer pair of `{}` is used for the *struct*, and inner pair of `{}` is used for the *member-array*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That makes sense, but apparently not to my compiler! Guess it's not fully supported in VS2010.