# g++ (4.7.2) bug or feature, when initializing static arrays at compile-time?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization, compiler-bug

Okay, so I was trying to do something clever by initializing a bunch of `constexpr static int const` arrays at compile-time. Even though the runtime-performance is not at all governed by initializing these arrays, it seemed like a fun little exercise. I wrote a test-setup to see if it was possible, and I ended up being able to do this:

```
struct Test
{
    constexpr static int const array[10] = Array<int, 10, 0, Increment>::array;
};

constexpr int const Test::array[10];

int main()
{
    cout << Test::array[3] << '\n';
}
```

Here, `Array` has a static member called `array` which contains 10 `int`s, starting at 0, where the value of each subsequent element is determined by a Template-Metaprogramming functor called `Increment` (i.e. `{0, 1, ..., 9}`). As expected, the program prints out the number `3`.

Awesome, right? I can just write functors now and initialize arrays will all kinds of funky patterns at compile-time. Next step: un-hardcode the array-size 10 by making `Test` a class-template like so:

```
template <size_t Size>
struct Test
{
    constexpr static int const array[Size] = Array<int, Size, 0, Increment>::array;
};

template <size_t Size>
constexpr int const Test<Size>::array[Size];

int main()
{
    cout << Test<10>::array[3] << '\n';
}
```

However, all of a sudden it doesn't compile anymore with the message:

```
test.cc:43:72: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Why does this happen? Is there a reason that this kind of initialization has become invalid once I turn the class into a class-template, or have I stumbled upon something unimplemented/buggy in GCC?

FYI, I can post the rest of my code (the implementation of `Array` for example) on request. For now I think this should be enough.

**EDIT** The error can be reproduced with a different, trivial, implementation of `Array` to save some space here:

```
template <size_t Size>
struct Array
{
    constexpr static int const array[Size] = {};
};

template <size_t Size>
struct Test
{
    constexpr static int const array[Size] = Array<Size>::array;
};
```

Comment: Try a newer gcc (ideone.com has 4.8 online). I cannot reproduce the error with 4.8.

Comment: @n.m. It gives the same error on C++11, and I'm not sure how to pass --std=c++11 to their 4.8.1 compiler...

Comment: @JorenHeit They have a C++11 mode and a regular C++ mode. You can also try Coliru.

Comment: @n.m. Tried http://gcc.godbolt.org/ where they provide gcc-4.8.1 and got the same issue.

Comment: @n.m. Same error on gcc-4.8 from Coliru.

Comment: So this must be your Array class. Post it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11: Correct std::array initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178264/c11-correct-stdarray-initialization)

Comment: @n.m. No it's not the array-class. I edited and posted a trivial example that leads to the same result.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No it's not.

Comment: @JorenHeit Although the question might not be exactly the same as yours, read the **answer(s)** carefully! The one with the most upvotes explains it very well, why you have to use an extra pair of braces when initializing a `std::array`.

Comment: clang 3.4 rejects the *constant* case with `error: array initializer must be an initializer list`. which seems natural with C-array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I still don't get what this has to do with my question. I'm not trying to initialize a `std::array`, nor anything that looks like it.

Comment: @JorenHeit I think the same explained there for `std::array` applies to your homebrew class!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not initializing the object. I'm initializing a member of the object, which is a normal C-array. NB. I understand why and when one needs multiple braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is illegal;

```
static const int a[10] = {};
static const int b[10] = a; // Illegal
```

So the bug of gcc is in fact for the non template case.

You may use `std::array` instead of C-array.

Comment: Even when both `a` and `b` are declared `constexpr`?

Comment: Thanks! I switched all my C-arrays for `std::array`s and, of course, used the double braces to initialize it, and now it works :-) Thank you kindly.