# Initialisation of std::array<>

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <array>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

static std::array<A, 4> x1 =
{
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
};

static std::array<A, 4> x2 =
{
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
    }
};

static std::array<A, 4> x3 =
{
       A{ 1, 2 },
       A{ 3, 4 },
       A{ 5, 6 },
       A{ 7, 8 }
};

static std::array<A, 4> x4 =
{
       A{ 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
};
```

Compiling with gcc:

```
$ gcc -c --std=c++11 array.cpp
array.cpp:15:1: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<A, 4ul>’
 };
 ^
$
```

NB1: Commenting out the first initialisation statement, the code compiles without error.
NB2: Converting all the initialisation to constructor calls yields the same results.
NB3: MSVC2015 behaves the same.

I can see why the first initialisation fails to compile, and why the second and third are OK.  (e.g. See [C++11: Correct std::array initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178264/c11-correct-stdarray-initialization).)

My question is:  Why exactly does the final initialisation compile?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see why the first assignment fails to compile, could you tell me more, please ? It's interesting !

Comment: @Ninetainedo - see the linked question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Short version: An initializer-clause that starts with `{` stops brace-elision. This is the case in the first example with `{1,2}`, but not in the third nor fourth which use `A{1,2}`. Brace-elision consumes the next N initializer-clauses (where N is dependent on the aggregate to be initialized), which is why only the first initializer-clause of the N must not begin with `{`.

---

In all implementations of the C++ Standard Library I know of, `std::array` is a struct which contains a C-style array. That is, you have an aggregate which contains a *sub-aggregate*, much like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array
{
    T __arr[N]; // don't access this directly!
};
```

When initializing a `std::array` from a *braced-init-list*, you'll therefore have to initialize the members of the *contained array*. Therefore, on those implementations, the explicit form is:

```
std::array<A, 4> x = {{ {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8} }};
```

The outermost set of braces refers to the `std::array` struct; the second set of braces refers to the nested C-style array.

---

C++ allows in aggregate initialization to omit certain braces when initializing nested aggregates. For example:

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        int i;
    };
    inner x;
};

outer e = { { 42 } };  // explicit braces
outer o = {   42   };  // with brace-elision
```

The rules are as follows (using a post-N4527 draft, which is post-C++14, but C++11 contained a defect related to this anyway):

> Braces can be elided in an *initializer-list* as follows. If the
>   *initializer-list* begins with a left brace, then the succeeding
>   comma-separated list of *initializer-clauses* initializes the members of
>   a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more
>   *initializer-clauses* than members. If, however, the *initializer-list*
>   for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only
>   enough *initializer-clauses* from the list are taken to initialize the
>   members of the subaggregate; any remaining *initializer-clauses* are
>   left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the
>   current subaggregate is a member.

Applying this to the first `std::array`-example:

```
static std::array<A, 4> x1 =
{
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
};
```

This is interpreted as follows:

```
static std::array<A, 4> x1 =
{        // x1 {
  {      //   __arr {
    1,   //     __arr[0]
    2    //     __arr[1]
         //     __arr[2] = {}
         //     __arr[3] = {}
  }      //   }

  {3,4}, //   ??
  {5,6}, //   ??
  ...
};       // }
```

The first `{` is taken as the initializer of the `std::array` struct. The *initializer-clauses* `{1,2}, {3,4}` etc. then are taken as the initializers of the subaggregates of `std::array`. Note that `std::array` only has a single subaggregate `__arr`. Since the first *initializer-clause* `{1,2}` begins with a `{`, the *brace-elision exception* does not occur, and the compiler tries to initialize the nested `A __arr[4]` array with `{1,2}`. The remaining *initializer-clauses* `{3,4}, {5,6}` etc. do not refer to any subaggregate of `std::array` and are therefore illegal.

In the third and fourth example, the first *initializer-clause* for the subaggregate of `std::array` **does not begin with a `{`**, therefore the brace elision exception is applied:

```
static std::array<A, 4> x4 =
{
       A{ 1, 2 }, // does not begin with {
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
};
```

So it is interpreted as follows:

```
static std::array<A, 4> x4 =
  {             // x4 {
                //   __arr {       -- brace elided
    A{ 1, 2 },  //     __arr[0]
    { 3, 4 },   //     __arr[1]
    { 5, 6 },   //     __arr[2]
    { 7, 8 }    //     __arr[3]
                //   }             -- brace elided
  };            // }
```

Hence, the `A{1,2}` causes all four *initializer-clauses* to be consumed to initialize the nested C-style array. If you add another initializer:

```
static std::array<A, 4> x4 =
{
       A{ 1, 2 }, // does not begin with {
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 },
       X
};
```

then this `X` would be used to initialize the next subaggregate of `std::array`. E.g.

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    inner i;
    int c;
};

outer o =
  {        // o {
           //   i {
    1,     //     a
    2,     //     b
           //   }
    3      //   c
  };       // }
```

Brace-elision consumes the next N initializer-clauses, where N is defined via the number of initializers required for the (sub)aggregate to be initialized. Therefore, it only matters whether or not the first of those N initializer-clauses starts with a `{`.

More similarly to the OP:

```
struct inner {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct outer {
    struct middle {
        inner i;
    };

    middle m;
    int c;
};

outer o =
  {              // o {
                 //   m {
    inner{1,2},  //     i
                 //   }
    3            //   c
  };             // }
```

Note that brace-elision applies recursively; we can even write the confusing

```
outer o =
  {        // o {
           //   m {
           //     i {
    1,     //       a
    2,     //       b
           //     }
           //   }
    3      //   c
  };       // }
```

Where we omit both the braces for `o.m` and `o.m.i`. The first two initializer-clauses are consumed to initialize `o.m.i`, the remaining one initializes `o.c`. Once we insert a pair of braces around `1,2`, it is interpreted as the pair of braces corresponding to `o.m`:

```
outer o =
  {        // o {
    {      //   m {
           //     i {
      1,   //       a
      2,   //       b
           //     }
    }      //   }
    3      //   c
  };       // }
```

Here, the initializer for `o.m` does start with a `{`, hence brace-elision does not apply. The initializer for `o.m.i` is `1`, which does not start with a `{`, hence brace-elision is applied for `o.m.i` and the two initializers `1` and `2` are consumed.

Comment: Nice, comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Comment: ++vote, excellent answer as usual. One question though: There's a post-N4527 draft already?

Comment: @Columbo Well, not officially. It's from the github repo, which makes it not an official working draft, but *interim work material*.

Comment: @dyp I did check out the Github repo, but there's N4527 only (which I've been using for a while).

Comment: @Columbo N4527 is from 2015-05-22, and the git repo contains commits after that date. So build from source, and you get some kind of post-N4527 "draft".