# How to make nested aggregate initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate-initialization

I have code as below

```
struct A {int i; int j;}

int main()
{
    array<A, 2> a;
    a = {{1,2},{3,4}}; //compilation error: not take a right-hand operand of 
                       //type 'initializer list' (or no acceptable conversion)
}
```

I think it is a nested aggregate initialization, but why not work? And How to make `a = {{1,2},{3,4}}` work by changing the code?

Find way work

```
a = { {{1,2},{3,4}} };
```

Don't know why?

Comment: That's assignment, not initialisation.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: True, but formally the `{}` initializer will be used to *initialize* a temporary RHS object, which will then be passed to `=` operator.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449898/initialisation-of-stdarray

Comment: @AnT This answered my question very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate initialization is *initialization*. `a` has already been initialized via default initialization. You can't initialize it again (well, you *could*, but let's not get into the deep magic).

If you want this to work, you must apply the braced-init-list to the declaration of `a`, not afterwards.

However, if you want to assign to `a`, you can always do this:

```
a = decltype(a){{{1,2},{3,4}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you're not initializing but rather assigning, consequently aggregate initialization is out of play here. This could work however, if you could give a little help to the compiler:

```
std::array<A, 2> a;
a = {A{1,2}, A{3,4}};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5c04880a12efc9a)