# Generating Array with some specific values

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to generate prime number. For this reason I have to initialize all array elements to `-1`. From c/c++, I came to know I have to initialize them by using a for loop. Please see the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        final int SIZE = 1000;
        int[] intArray = new int[SIZE];
        Arrays.fill(intArray, -1);

        for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            intArray[i] = -1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        }

    }
```

In java is there any better way to do this?

Comment: why do you have to initialize an array with -1?

Comment: BTW, in C++ you'd better use `std::vector` that has a special constructor for this: `std::vector<int> intArray(SIZE, -1)`.

Comment: This isn't java specific, but try to follow a consistent way of spacing operators and operands. Like, in the first for loop you have `i=0` in the second one `i = 0`. Either follow the first style or the second one. Don't mix.

Comment: Why did you use `Arrays#fill`? What do you think that does? Why do you think so?

Comment: @Petr, Thanks. I did not knew it.

Comment: Look at the implementation of Arrays.fill, it's just a for loop as well, other for readablity and "code-sleakness", there is no difference... just FYI http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays-source.html

Comment: This looks like a more appropriate question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you would post about this on Code Review, post your whole prime-number-generation code. I'm sure that in the end, you'll end up throwing this part of the code away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use [Arrays.fill(int[] a, int val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int%29) method like this -

```
Arrays.fill(intArray, -1);
```

The `Arrays.fill()` populates the array - `intArray` with the specified value `val`. So you don't need to initialize the `intArray` using the for loop.

And one more thing, in c++ it is also possible to initialize array with some value like this, without using the for loop. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178264/c11-correct-stdarray-initialization)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Arrays.fill(intArray, -1);` already fills your array, so there's no need for the redundant `for` loop following that statement.

You can also just remove your `final int SIZE`, and say `int[] intArray = new int[1000];`. When you need to get the length/size of the array, you can just say `intArray.length`.