# How to emplace to a std::vector of std::array?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdarray, emplace

With a vector of vectors, I can do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vov;
vov.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{0, 0});
```

However, the equivalent fails for the vector of std::array:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> voa;
voa.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{0,0});
```

What is the correct way to emplace an array inside vector?

Edit:

Yes, you can create std::array from <strike>initializer list</strike>:

```
std::array<int, 2> a = {0, 0}
```

works fine.

The error:

```
error C2664: 'std::array<int,2>::array(const std::array<int,2> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::initializer_list<int>' to 'const std::array<int,2> &'
```

Comment: does it matter if the array is inside a vector? Don't you get the same error when trying to construct an array that is not in a vector from the init list ? Please inlucde the error in the quesiton

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893700/580083

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have a ctor for emplace_back to forward to.

Comment: I think here you can find why it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) doesn't have any constructors, it's initialization follows aggregate initialization.

You have two options, either use `push_back` instead of `emplace_back` with a brace-init-list:

```
voa.push_back({ 0, 0 });
```

Or you can use `std::array`'s (implicit) copy and move constructors and construct a temporary `std::array`:

```
voa.emplace_back(std::array<int>{0, 0}); // pre C++17
voa.emplace_back(std::array{0, 0});      // C++17
```

Ultimately both methods should generate the same machine code.

---

In response to your edit:

```
std::array<int, 2> a = {0, 0};
```

is NOT the same as

```
std::array<int, 2> a = std::initializer_list<int>{0, 0};
```

`{0, 0}` is a *brace-init-list*, which doesn't have a type.  This is why you can't use them as an argument to a templated function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction) for more details.