# Why can't I create an array of automatic variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration

In C++0x (ohh! read C++11), we have automatic type inference. One thing which made me curious was that I can't create an array of auto variables. For example:

```
auto A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // Error!
```

Any ideas why this might have been disallowed?

Comment: Why does everybody want to abuse new language features.

Comment: @Martin: I have absolutely no intent of abusing a very beautiful language such as C++. I'm just curious about the reasons (technical, ethical etc. whatsoever) behind this decision.

Comment: @Martin: You have to touch the surfaces to know where the walls are before starting to run blindly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`auto` deduces every brace-enclosed initializer list to a `std::initializer_list<T>`. (See §7.1.6.4.6 including the example).
Unfortunately you cannot initialize an array or even `std::array` from a `std::initializer_list` once you have obtained it, but you can use a `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
  auto x = {1,2,3};
  std::array<int, 3> foo1 = x; // won't work for whatever reason
  std::vector<int> foo2 = x; // works as expected
  return 0;
}
```

Of course this defeats the whole purpose of what you are trying to do.

I tried writing a work around called `make_array` but had to realize that this cannot ever work as the size of an `initializer_list` isn't part of its template arguments and so you only instantiate one `make_array` template for each `T`. This sucks.

```
template<typename T> 
auto make_array(const std::initializer_list<T>& x) 
     -> std::array<T, x.size()> { } // maaah
```

Well, apparently you can go for the variadic-template hack mentioned here [How do I initialize a member array with an initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549524/how-do-i-initialize-a-member-array-with-an-initializer-list)

Answer (score 5):

Because `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is purely a syntactic construct- it is not an expression and does not have a type. Therefore, `auto` cannot deduce its type from it.

Comment: Such a shame, I know languages which have been able to do that for years

Comment: But `auto x = {1,2}` declares `x` as a `std::initializer_list<int>`. So this is not exactly true.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ok, so what do you think about auto x = {1, 2, 3, 4};? Is it going to work or not? What value will x contain? If x is 1, how did compiler deducted its type now?

Comment: @pmr: You beat me to this example! :-)

Comment: Eugene Homyakov: Such languages wouldn't work with the same type system. I guess you're talking about, for example Python, but it really is fundamentally different. In Python {} used on the right of an assignation can only be a dictionary, while in C++ it could be any custom type.

Comment: @pmr: I expect that the Committee forgot to add a specific rule for `auto[]`.