# Why auto is not allowed in template function for creating a built-in array?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, auto

This code below does not compile:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
void CreateArr(const Ts&... args)
{
    auto arr[sizeof...(args) + 1]{ args... };
}

int main()
{
    CreateArr(1, 2, 3);
}
```

due to the following errors:

- `'arr'`: in a direct-list-initialization context, the type for `'auto [6]'` can only be deduced from a single initializer expression
- `auto [6]'`: an array cannot have an element type that contains `'auto'`
- 'initializing': cannot convert from `'const int'` to `'std::initializer_list<int>'`

My questions are:

- **Why cannot I use `auto` to define the type of the array?**
- **How to define it properly to work with the template?**

Comment: Nothing to do with templates, you can't use `auto` for a built-in array as the error says.

Comment: Note that the array size should be `sizeof...(args)` not `sizeof...(args) + 1`, if you intend to have the array of as many parameters you passed to the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why cannot I use `auto` to define the type of the array?

For the same reason, following does not work/ allowed!

```
auto ele[]{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

More reads: [Why can't I create an array of automatic variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107606/why-cant-i-create-an-array-of-automatic-variables)

---

> How to define it properly to work with the template?

Use the [`std::common_type_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) for specifying the type

```
#include <type_traits> //  std::common_type_t

template<typename... Ts>
void CreateArr(const Ts&... args) 
{
    std::common_type_t<Ts...> arr[sizeof...(args)]{ args... };
   
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<int[sizeof...(args)]>, "is not array!");
}
```

**([See a Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sxsqKMzK7))**