# How to initialize a member of array type which has no default constructor in C++98?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++98

I would like to define an member which is an array of a type which can not have a default constructor. The array must contain the actual objects, not pointers. Dynamic memory allocation (`new`/`delete`) can not be used.

Apparently this is not trivially possible in C++98, as initializer lists are not available yet? What are the alternatives?

Here [a MVP](https://godbolt.org/z/6dh54nbn3):

```cpp
struct I {
    const bool b;
};

struct O {
    I a[2];

    O() : a{true, false} {}
} o;
```

Error message with GCC:

```
<source>: In constructor 'O::O()':
<source>:8:12: error: extended initializer lists only available with '-std=c++11' or '-std=gnu++11' [-Werror=c++11-extensions]
    8 |     O() : a{true, false} {}
      |            ^
```

Comment: Are you allowed to add anything into class `I` ?  [Initialize a constant sized array in an initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837078/initialize-a-constant-sized-array-in-an-initializer-list)

Comment: You can add a static data member to `O` and then use it to initialize `a` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78040034/12002570).

Comment: @user12002570 yes I can add `static` data members to both `I` and `O`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036261/how-to-initialize-a-member-of-array-type-which-has-no-default-constructor-in-c/78040034?noredirect=1#comment137579277_78036261) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78040034/5534993) from [@user12002570](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12002570/user12002570) combined with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837202/5534993) from [@Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) I designed the following solution:

```cpp
struct I {
    I(int (&a)[4]) : i(a) {}
    int (&i)[4];
};

struct O {

    int m[2][4]; // data for initialization

    struct Container {
        I a[2]; // to be initialized
    } array;

    static Container generateArray(int (&array)[2][4]){
        Container c = {array[0], array[1]};
        return c;
    }

    O() : array(generateArray(m)) {}
} o;
```

In this example the reference to a `int[4]` needs to be initialized when constructing `I` (in contrast to `const bool` in the question).

It wraps the member array to be initialized into a `struct` "`Container`".
This container can be initialized within the constructor initialization list of the outer class `O` using a function (`generateArray()`). In this case the generator function takes a reference to a multi-dimensional array as argument.

This complies with [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/dW9h6x3qW) and [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/MfesWjfvs).

In addition to previous answers this solution uses an initializer with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

> In C++98, What are the alternatives?

One alternative is to add a static data member into class `O` and then use it to initialize `a` as shown below:

```
struct O {
   
    I a[2];  
    
    static I const data[2];
    O() : a(data){}
} ; 

I const O::data[2] = {true, false};
int main()
{   O o;
    std::cout << (o.a[0]).b << " " << (o.a[1]).b; //prints 1 0 as expected
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M119hb8Wc)

Comment: Clang rejects this; sure it isn't a GCC extension?

Comment: @ildjarn I'm no aware if gcc has any such extension. I'll check this on the gcc forum and if I don't find anything I'll file a bug to see if they have any extension.

Comment: @user12002570 did you get any insight about if this is an extension?

Comment: @user5534993 Yes, it is a gcc bug.

Comment: @user5534993 If you can add static members in both `I` and `O`, then can you also add default ctor to `I`? If not, is there a reason?

Comment: @user12002570 I can not add a default constructor to `I` as it needs be be initialized with data which is determined at runtime. That data is provided by the constructor of `O`.