# C++: Initialize a member array within a constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, constexpr, initializer-list

I am implementing a class in c++17 that needs to be able to construct an object at compile time using a `constexpr` constructor. The object has an array member which I cannot seem to be able to initialize through an argument.

I've been trying to use `std::initializer_list` for this, something along the lines of:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
 char data[100];

 constexpr A(std::initializer_list<char> s): data(s) {}
};

int main() {
  constexpr A a{"abc"};
}
```

But this doesnt work for some reason.

`clang 6.0` (also tried later versions) tells me I'm wrong although I'm doing what it says:

```sh
test_initializer_list.cpp:7:46: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
 constexpr A(std::initializer_list<char> s): data(s) {}
```

(Note that if I gives it a string literal directly, like `data("abc")`, it does compile)

`g++` (7.5.0) says that I cannot use an initializer list for some reason - but if so, what can I use?

```sh
test_initializer_list.cpp:7:52: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::initializer_list<char>' to 'char [100]'
  constexpr A(std::initializer_list<char> s): data(s) {}
                                                    ^
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize a member array with an initializer\_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549524/how-do-i-initialize-a-member-array-with-an-initializer-list)

Comment: What makes you think that `"abc"` is (or can be converted into) `std::initializer_list<char>`?

Comment: @dfri - Thanks but not exactly, because they don't need constexpr
@Evg - you are right in principal, but trying to put there `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is going to be long, but bear with me.

---

You can't initialize an array with an `std::initializer_list`.

When you write something like `int arr[] = {1,2,3}`, the part enclosed in braces is not an `std::initializer_list`.

> If you don't believe me, consider a similar initialization for a structure:
>
> ```
> struct A {int x; const char *y;};
> A a = {1, "2"};
> ```
>
> Here, `{1, "2"}` can't possibly be an `std::initializer_list`, because the elements have different types.

The C++ grammar calls those brace-enclosed lists [*braced-init-list*s](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list).

`std::initializer_list` is a magical class (not implementable in standard C++, that is) that *can be constructed from* a braced-init-list.

As you noticed, `std::initializer_list` can't be used in place of a braced-init-list. "Braced-init-list" refers to a specific grammatical construct, so an initializer for an array (e.g. in a member init list) must literally *be* a brace-enclosed list. You can't save this list to a variable, and initialize an array with it later.

```
constexpr A() : data{'1','2','3'} {} // Valid
constexpr A(initializer_list<char>/*or whatever*/ list) : data{list} {} // Not possible
```

A possible solution is to use a loop to copy elements from `std::initializer_list` into the array.

Since the constructor is `constexpr`, the array must be initialized with *something*; initialize it with zeroes using `: data{}`:

```
constexpr A(std::initializer_list<char> s) : data{} {/*copy elements here*/}
```

Now `A a({'1','2','3'});` will work. But `A a("123");` still won't.

A string literal (`"123"`) is neither a braced-init-list nor an `std::initializer_list`, and it can't be converted to them.

There's a special rule for initializing `char` arrays with string literals (`char x[] = "123";`). In addition to a braced-init-list, the grammar allows a string literal to be used there.

It has to be a string *literal*, i.e. a string enclosed in quotes; a `const char *` variable or an another array of `char` won't do.

If you want `A a("123");` to be valid, the parameter of the constructor needs to be a `const char *` (there are some other options, but they don't help much here). Use a loop to copy the characters from the pointed memory into the array. Don't forget to initialize the array with zeroes (`: data{}`), because your constructor is `constexpr`.

There's a third option: replace `char data[100]` with an `std::array`, and also make the parameter of the constructor an `std::array`. Unlike plain arrays, those can be copied, so `: data(list)` will work. And `std::array` can be initialized with both a braced-init-list (`A a({'1','2','3'});`), and a brace-enclosed string literal (`A a({"123"});`).

And there's yet another option you have: remove the constructor. Your `struct` will then become an *aggregate* (simply saying, a struct that has no custom constructors and can be initialized member-wise with a braced-init-list). Then both `A a{{'1','2','3'}};`, `A a{'1','2','3'};` (braces can be omitted), and `A a{"123"};` will work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess I had a feeling about copying in the function body solution (though for constexpr this is more painful) but had no idea about `braced-init-list` vs `initialization-list` not being the same which was frustrating. Thanks also for the std::array idea!