# Variadic constructor is being preferred to the user provided move constructor except when defaulted

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, move-semantics

Consider the following snippet of code where I have a move-only `Wrapper` object that forwards the arguments to the underlying data on construction. Now if I use this `Wrapper` object inside another move-only class (`SomeObject` in this case), unless the move constructor for `SomeObject` is defaulted, it doesn't compile.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T> class Wrapper {
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  Wrapper(Args &&... args) : _data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

  Wrapper(const Wrapper &) = delete;

  Wrapper(Wrapper &&other) : _data(std::move(other)) {}

  T &get() const { return _data; }

protected:
  T _data;
};

struct SomeObject {
  SomeObject(const SomeObject &) = delete;
  SomeObject(SomeObject &&other) : x(std::move(other.x)) {}
  //SomeObject(SomeObject &&other) = default; // this works!
  SomeObject(int val) : x(val) {}

  Wrapper<int> x;
};

int main() {
  SomeObject obj(10);
  return 0;
}
```

With gcc 6.3 we get:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Wrapper<T>::Wrapper(Wrapper<T>&&) [with T = int]’: 
test.cpp:20:56:   required from here 
test.cpp:10:52: error: cannot convert ‘std::remove_reference<Wrapper<int>&>::type {aka Wrapper<int>}’ to ‘int’ in initialization
Wrapper(Wrapper &&other) : _data(std::move(other)) {}
                                                ^
```

Is there something I am missing here? Aren't the user provided move constructor in `SomeObject` the same as the one the compiler would define when defaulted?

The only thing close to this that I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953611/are-variadic-constructors-supposed-to-hide-the-implicitly-generated-ones) but I feel like this is a different case since my move constructor for `SomeObject` isn't passing `const` types.

Comment: Use `Wrapper(Wrapper &&other) : _data(std::move(other._data)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Look at your code:

```
Wrapper(Wrapper &&other) : _data(std::move(other)) {}
T _data;
```

in your case, T is int. How do you want to initialize `int` from `Wrapper<int>`?

Comment: More explicitly, change ```std::move(other)``` to ```std::move(other._data)```