# gcc not_fn implementation: why does _Not_fn accept additional int parameter?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, libstdc++

Recently I have taken a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/09d66f495520860fb1a02a671eb02b246e6bc42b/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L909) of [`std::not_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn)  function template provided by *gcc*.

The return type of this function template is `_Not_fn` - a wrapper class template which negates a wrapped callable object.

It turns out, that [`_Not_fn` constructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/09d66f495520860fb1a02a671eb02b246e6bc42b/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L853) accepts an additional `int` parameter which is not explicitly used:

```
template<typename _Fn2>
    _Not_fn(_Fn2&& __fn, int)
    : _M_fn(std::forward<_Fn2>(__fn)) { }
```

The call to the constructor looks like that:

```
template<typename _Fn>
inline auto not_fn(_Fn&& __fn) 
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<std::decay_t<_Fn>, _Fn&&>::value)
{
    return _Not_fn<std::decay_t<_Fn>>{std::forward<_Fn>(__fn), 0}; // <- 0 is passed here
}
```

**Question:**

What is the purpose of this additional `int` parameter? Why does *gcc* implementation need it?

Comment: This is common enough for prioritizing overloads when SFINAE is involved. Perhaps it used to be implemented differently and this parameter was left in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dummy parameter was added because the implementer didn't want the perfect forwarding constructor to be a [better match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953611/241631) than the copy-constructor for non-`const` arguments.

Consider this example

```
struct _Not_fn
{
    template<typename _Fn2>
    _Not_fn(_Fn2&&)
    { /* */ }

    _Not_fn(const _Not_fn&)
    { /* */ }
};

_Not_fn f([]{});
_Not_fn f1(f);         // calls perfect forwarding constructor
_Not_fn f2(const_cast<const _Not_fn&>(f));    // calls copy constructor
```

The same problem exists for the move constructor as well. The introduction of the dummy `int` parameter solves this headache.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e046f8a8ecb17b24)

The [change](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/f3bc5fecf2cb6f298d12c30cf15306f843bcdce4) was introduced to fix [bug 70564](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70564).

Comment: Here's the commit: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/f3bc5fecf2cb6f298d12c30cf15306f843bcdce4

Comment: @chris Thanks for finding that! I've linked to the PR and the commit in the answer.

Comment: Now it makes sense for me! I feel that if I were an implementer I would do the same bug...

Comment: `, int` sure beats writing that constraint!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons.

The first reason is, a constructor that takes 2 arguments is not a converting constructor.  Even explicit conversions can sometimes be called or selected for overload by accident.  By adding `int`, questions about convertibility are clear (it isn't).

A second reason could be that it is legacy code from an overload resolution ordering trick.  If you create two overloads, one which takes `int` the other `...`, the `int` will be picked over the `...` when both are viable.

If at one point the type had a more complex construction it could have had that `int` and `...` overload.  The `int` may just be a legacy of uncleaned-up code.

Answer (score 0):

An off-topic sidenote: libstdcx++ defines these ctors explicitly:

```
template<typename _Fn2>
    _Not_fn(_Fn2&& __fn, int)
    : _M_fn(std::forward<_Fn2>(__fn)) { }

      _Not_fn(const _Not_fn& __fn) = default;
      _Not_fn(_Not_fn&& __fn) = default;
      ~_Not_fn() = default;

/*other member functions*/


   template<typename _Fn>
    inline auto
    not_fn(_Fn&& __fn)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<std::decay_t<_Fn>, _Fn&&>::value)
    {
      return _Not_fn<std::decay_t<_Fn>>{std::forward<_Fn>(__fn), 0};
    }
```

[But libcxx doesn't declare any ctor explicitly](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/functional#L2411)

```
  __not_fn_imp() = delete;
```

`__not_fn_imp
     ┃  ┃ (Class)
     ┃  ┃ operator() (Method)
     ┃  ┃ operator() (Method)
     ┃  ┃ operator() (Method)
     ┃  ┃ operator() (Method)
     ┃  ┃ __fd (Field)`

So,

```
template <class _RawFunc>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __not_fn_imp<decay_t<_RawFunc> >
not_fn(_RawFunc&& __fn) {
  return __not_fn_imp<decay_t<_RawFunc> >(_VSTD::forward<_RawFunc>(__fn));
}
```

Can find the correct (cpoy)ctor.